# SwiftUI elements noticeably less crisp than AppKit? How can I fix this

Tags: swiftui, appkit

Here are some screenshots to demonstrate. For the text, the top one is an NSAttributedString displayed in SwiftUI with NSViewRepresentable, and the bottom text is a plain `Text` view struct. For the SFSymbols, starting from the right. `Image(systemName: image)`, the middle is `Image(nsImage: nsImage)`, and the far left is NSViewRepresentable which holds an NSView that draws the NSImage with:

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        image?.draw(at: .zero, from: bounds, operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
    }
```

The symbol used for all three is the SFSymbol: `clear`

Does anyone know why SwiftUI seems to have noticeably less crisp display than AppKit? Is this a setting I'm missing?

Minimum reproducable example:

```
import SwiftUI


struct MyLabel: NSViewRepresentable {
    var string: String

  init(_ string: String) {
    self.string = string
  }

  func makeNSView(context _: Context) -> NSTextField {
    let tf = NSTextField(frame: .zero)
    tf.stringValue = string
    tf.isBordered = false
    tf.drawsBackground = false
    tf.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    tf.isBezeled = false
    tf.isEditable = false
    tf.isSelectable = false
    tf.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
    tf.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    tf.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    tf.font = NSFont.titleBarFont(ofSize: 18)
    tf.textColor = .white
    return tf
  }

  func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextField, context _: Context) {
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("THIS IS SWIFTUI").font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold)).border(.blue)
        MyLabel("THIS IS APPKIT").frame(maxWidth: .infinity).border(.red)
      }
      .scaleEffect(4).offset(x: 900, y: 650)
        .border(.green)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have not observed this. Do you have any references that state this is a general problem?

Comment: I think you should make a minimal, reproducible example for this problem.

Comment: @soundflix Render a SwiftUI `Text` or `Image` view, and then render an AppKit `NSTextField` or `NSImage` inside SwiftUI, and you'll see it. One is noticeably more crisp. If you use `.scaleEffect` on the views it becomes much more obvious.

Comment: @soundflix I've added code to reproduce it. Start a new macOS app project, replace ContentView with that code and run it. Photo included of what it looks like.

Comment: @soundflix Do I have any references? Is that photo not a reference? Does that not look noticeably less crisp to you?

Comment: I put your example in a fresh XCode 14.2 SwiftUI macOS app. I see the same crispness for AppKit and SwiftUI, even if I zoom in a lot. I don't know why it is different by you.

Comment: In your example, you should add `.foregroundColor(.white)` to the `Text` view to make both the same color. In fact, the only difference I see is a color difference, even after adding the white modifier. SwiftUI is a tiny bit more gray/yellowish.

Comment: That's probably the blur. To be fair you did seem to struggle noticing a difference in the photos I posted, whereas to me there's a stark difference even without the scaling. I've tried setting the text to white(screenshot added), do you really not see a resolution difference in that screenshot? Only color? This is a new project on macOS 13.4. I did check SystemPreferences, but I didn't find a "Make SwiftUI less blurry" setting that I forget to toggle or anything.

Comment: I've also added a screenshot at 15x scale, you must see a difference there. The bottom text has perfect edges, the SwiftUI text is both more gray, and heavily pixelated.

Comment: I never meant that I can't see a difference in your screenshots, they are obvious to me, and I'm not doubting you are experiencing less crispiness either. What I meant is, I can't reproduce it. We have to carefully investigate what is the issue. What I meant with "reference" is, did somebody else notice this yet. If I it were really a problem of AppKit vs. SwiftUI, there would be some publication about, I guess.